# jQuery: Hide div with no ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

How can I hide a div with no ID? I have an application which creates few stickies. Some of them have no ID and some of the do have. How can I hide the ones with no ID?

The position is not always the same.

This is what I get in the HTML where I want to hide the last one.
[image]

Is it possible I can hide the one with no ID? Note that the rest which have ID's, is a number generated randomly.

Thanks alot.

Comment: Will there only be a single div with class `sticky` that needs to be hidden?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("div.sticky:not([id])").hide();
```

The main idea is to use `:not([id])` selector with element selector.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/57uQ8/

Answer (score 5):

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/d2956/2

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("div.sticky").each(function(b){
        if (!$(this).attr('id')){
            $(this).hide(); 
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

will probably do it, assuming you want to show ONLY divs with no IDS and divs with class sticky

Comment: Thank you. I will be using Igor's instead because of the less coding.